# Metadata API error "Need to specify full name" yet fullname field is populated in request FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION

Tags: metadata-api

**Use case**: Cloning `ListViews` in Apex using the [Apex Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

I created a simple code snippet:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service =  MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
MetadataService.ListView[] cloneListViews   = new List<MetadataService.ListView>();
MetadataService.ListView cloneListView = new MetadataService.ListView();    
// populate the fields in cloneListView including field fullName by copying from some retrieved ListViews
cloneListViews.add(cloneListView);
MetadataService.SaveResult[] results = 
      service.createMetadata(new List<MetadataService.ListView> ( cloneListViews ));
```

Yet results shows a failure with this message:

```
fullname=User00_Opptys_Closing_This_Month
Message:Need to specify full name, Name:User00_Opptys_Closing_This_Month, Delimiter:. 
        statusCode: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically a face plant but since it took me an hour to figure this out I thought I would save someone else the time

- ListViews are associated with objects and as such, the metadata's `fullname` has to be the `ObjectApiName.ListViewApiName`. If using namespaces, then `Namespace__.ObjectApiName.ListViewApiName`
- Simply making `fullname='User00_Opptys_Closing_This_Month'` is not enough, it needs to be `'Opportunity.User00_Opptys_Closing_This_Month'`
- The error message hints at this problem by including the `Delimiter:.` in the message
- There is a reason the metadata field is called `fullname` but if you only sporadically use the Metadata API then this is easy to get confused with the API name for the ListView such as you see in the Force.com point-and-click UI, i.e. `User00_Opptys_Closing_This_Month`.
- The documentation in the [MetaData API on `fullName`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/metadata.htm#meta_fullname) only mentions that the `objectAPIName` is required for fields, not `ListViews` (I filed doc feedback on this point).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when migrating process builder Flow with Metadata API. The solution was to specify the flow version like MyFlow**-1**