# Generation of Apex code from WSDL

Tags: apex, wsdl

I've been trying to parse the metadata WSDL provided by Salesforce to generate apex code that might help in using the metadata API. But somehow when I parse the WSDL it keeps giving me the error -

[image]

Does somebody have any answer to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, just install the [Apex Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from GitHub

You get:

- Dozens of examples of how to retrieve and update various metadata objects (fields, listviews, etc.) See class `MetadataServiceExamples.cls`
- A well-tested library that is easy to use with dozens of examples around the web, including here on SFSE. Here's [a recent post by me](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156716/metadata-api-error-need-to-specify-full-name-yet-fullname-field-is-populated-i) showing some simple code

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in the Apexclass you've used the restricted keyword 'metadata'. Try to change(or map) this keyword to other world.

Comment: I am afraid i still am unsure about where the changes should be made. The keyword `metadata` is used several times in the WSDL and they might be for different purposes. I just don't want to create any more errors out of it. Could you please be a little more specific ?

Comment: Could you show the example of your code ?

Comment: Well the apex code is not yet generated since I am unable to parse the XML/WSDL file. Here's a link to my git repository. The file is named as _metadata.xml_ . Can you please have a look at it? Or may be try to parse it in your own org if it's not too much of a pain? Thanks in advance!

[Here's the repository ->](https://github.com/mohit0094/demoRepo)

Comment: Ok. Could you explein me why you want to create Apex Class with method's which is currently implemented in the org ?

Comment: These methods are not available in the org directly, you either have to parse a WSDL file or add the apex classes as @cropredy mentioned in his answer, unfortunately none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've found the solution to it.

So the GitHub repository of Andrew Fawcett has a **Deploy to Salesforce** button that deploys all the code to your dev org, I already had the same classes in my org but I did not pay attention to the error.

The **create()** method has been deprecated. I had to use **createMetadata()**.

The code is working fine.

Thanks for the help @Adamo and @cropredy.